# Поочередный ввод информации из файлов в Bash

Tags: linux, bash, shell

Допустим, я имею 2 текстовых файла и мне нужно написать скрипт, который поочередно выводит одну строчку из 1го файла, потом одну строчку из 2го файла, потом опять одну строку из 1го файла и т д.

**Т.е:** просто чередовать строки из одного файла и из другого.
Как это можно сделать?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

например, так (если файлы содержат одинаковое количество строк):

```
$ paste -d '\n' file1 file2
```

Comment: Спасибо. Я нашел немного другое решение, через sed. Там как раз отлично получилось контролировать вывод.

Answer (score 2):

Можно одновременно построчно читать оба файла, вызывая в цикле встроенную команду `read` по одному разу для чтения очередной строки каждого файла:

```
#!/bin/bash

exec 3<file1.txt
exec 4<file2.txt

f1=1
f2=1
while [ $f1 -gt 0  ] || [ $f2 -gt 0 ]
do 
    if  [ $f1 -ne 0 ] && read -r strfile1 <&3  ; then
        echo $strfile1
    else
        f1=0
    fi
    if  [ $f2 -ne 0 ] && read -r strfile2 <&4  ; then
        echo $strfile2
    else
        f2=0
    fi
done
```

Открываете для чтения файлы командой `exec`, связывая их с дескрипторами (обычно дескрипторы 0, 1 и 2 уже заняты под stdin, stdout и stderr), которые затем используете в `read`. Переменные `f1` и `f2` используем как признаки конца файлов.

Ключ -r в `read` означает -- `raw input - disables interpretion of backslash escapes and line-continuation in the read data`

Естественно, файлы могут быть разной длины.